# Why in gated recurrent unit gates are controlled by only one layer perceptrons?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, perceptron, gru

Why don't I see a GRU anywhere with more than one layer of perceptrons inside, it's pretty obvious to try to put more layers in there, but I don't see anyone doing that

Comment: Could you be more precise? There isn’t any “layer of perceptron” in GRU.

Comment: I think he means "why are gates" computed using only a single linear layer instead of more complex multi-layer perceptrons. It's a good question... There are many works that use "deep-gated" recurrent units... For instance https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-019-2972-5 .

Comment: @bomzh it'd be nice if this was clarified, since there may be different interpretations of this question.